# Can my Linux-mint become vulnerable after updating?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, virus, malware, virus-removal

According to [Linux Mint's blog post](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2994):

> The website of linux-mint is hacked and some ISOs are replaced with
>   backdoored operating system.

I am installing my operating system from a few weeks ago. How can I check if my operation system is vulnerable or not?

If I update my system is it possible for it to become infected?

Comment: The link you provided states "if there is a file in /var/lib/man.cy, then this is an infected ISO."

Comment: the out put is "bash: cd: /var/lib/man.cy No such file or directory"

Comment: @GAD3R seems like your system is not affected with this backdoor, but since they're still working on it, stay tuned with the news for more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from [Linux Mint's blog](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2994)

> Does this affect you?
>
> As far as we know, the only compromised edition was Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon edition.
>
> If you downloaded another release or another edition, this does not affect you. If you downloaded via torrents or via a direct HTTP link, this doesn’t affect you either.
>
> Finally, the situation happened today, so it should only impact people who downloaded this edition on February 20th.

They claim that the update servers weren't compromised so if you didn't download the compromised iso directly you should be safe. And you can check your iso with provided md5 checksums to see if your downloaded version is backdoored.

You can also check for the existance of **/var/lib/man.cy** file and if its present then you have a vulnerable version.